# TypeError: proficiency is not a function - but it is

Tags: javascript

I have written a function as follows

```
function proficiency(level) {
    if (level >= 1 && level < 5) {
    proficiency = 2;
    } else if (level >= 5 && level < 9) {
    proficiency = 3;
    } else if (level >= 9 && level < 13){
    proficiency = 4;
    } else if (level >= 13 && level < 17) {
    proficiency = 5;
    } else if (level >= 17 && level <= 20) {
    proficiency = 6;
    }

    return proficiency;
}
```

Then I run it within another function called "Roll the Dice" as it is a D&D Character Generator and this would reflect dice rolling:

```
proficiency(level);
```

The first time I do it, it works fine. No errors. The function happens accordingly. The SECOND time I try it, it gives me the following error.

```
TypeError: proficiency is not a function
```

This happens every time I refresh the page. I'm declaring the function globally so I don't know how this continues to happen.

Comment: Don't use the function name as a variable name

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting your proficiency function with the proficiency integer INSIDE the function. So the first time you call `proficiency(level)`, it is seen as a function, but the second time you call it, it is overwritten with a value from 2 to 6. Since `proficiency(level)` is invalid for integers, it throws that error

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're running into is one of closures. You're using the variable `proficiency` twice.

The first time your code gets parsed, the `function proficiency()` gets hoisted to the top of the file, and the variable `proficiency` is that function.

Then once you call the function the first time, you are overwriting it.

```
function proficiency() {
    proficiency = 2; // Here, no matter which if you're inside.
}
```

Because you don't declare `proficiency` at the top of your function with the `var` keyword, it then gets declared at the outer scope, most likely `window`. So the next time you go to call your function, `proficiency` is no longer the function you declare it as, but the value from the first time the function was executed.

As was quickly stated in the comments as I was writing this answer, the easiest way to avoid this is to not have the variable within the function have the same name as the function. It also makes your code easier to read.

```
function proficiency(level) {
    var result;

    if (level >= 1 && level < 5) {
        result = 2;
    } else if (level >= 5 && level < 9) {
        result= 3;
    } else if (level >= 9 && level < 13){
        result= 4;
    } else if (level >= 13 && level < 17) {
        result= 5;
    } else if (level >= 17 && level <= 20) {
        result= 6;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I have tried the above code and I get that I'm running the variable twice. Now what I get as a product is rather than say "4 Proficiency", I get the whole function written on the screen.

'function proficiency(level) { var result; if (level >= 1 && level < 5) { result = 2; } else if (level >= 5 && level < 9) { result= 3; } else if (level >= 9 && level < 13){ result= 4; } else if (level >= 13 && level < 17) { result= 5; } else if (level >= 17 && level <= 20) { result= 6; } return result; } Proficiency'

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about what you're getting as a result versus what you're expecting. They unfortunately don't format code like that in comments.

Answer (score 1):

By doing `proficiency = X;` in your function, you are creating a global variable called `proficiency`, that is not a function. You should declare it in the scope of the function by using the keyword `var`:

```
function proficiency(level) {
    var proficiency;
    if (level >= 1 && level < 5) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your function name `proficiency` is conflicting with your variable name `proficiency`. You could return the value right away to avoid introducing another variable.

```
function proficiency(level) {
    if (level >= 1 && level < 5) {
        return 2;
    } else if (level >= 5 && level < 9) {
        return 3;
    } else if (level >= 9 && level < 13){
        return 4;
    } else if (level >= 13 && level < 17) {
        return 5;
    } else if (level >= 17 && level <= 20) {
        return 6;
    }

    throw new Error('Invalid character level');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#The_function_declaration_(function_statement)) points out:

> A function declaration also creates a variable with the same name as
>   the function name. Thus, unlike those defined by function expressions,
>   functions defined by function declarations can be accessed by their
>   name in the scope they were defined in.

So after you run your function once, you effectively destroy the function. You can see this by logging `console.log(typeof proficiency)` before and after calling the function the first time. The first time you'll get `function`, the second time you'll get `number`.

Solution? Use a variable name other than `proficiency` within the function.

Answer (score 0):

I realized what I was doing wrong.

Yes, I needed to differentiate the function (proficiency) from the variable (proficiency). Done. But then I was getting garbage until I realized what a dolt I was.

I needed to create a variable within the roll the dice function

```
var prof = proficiency(level);
```

Once I did that, I called prof within the jquery.html statement and voila, problem solved.  Thank you for showing me the way.